# Why SonarScanner ignores sonar.sources value (You must define the following mandatory properties)?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I would like you to help me with a problem that I have when executing: 'build now', because when I execute it the console output shows a series of failures

One of the failures was and still is, the properties of the file, I have already configured them and it is still giving faults, I have also saved them in the project directory, but nothing keeps failing.

these are the properties which i have in my project

```
sonar.projectKey=sistema_integracion
sonar.projectName=sistema_integracion
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.projectDescription=proyecto_asir
sonar.source=C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\proyecto_integracion\spring_boot\src\main\java\hello
sonar.language=java
sonar.java.binaries=. 
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.scm.disabled=True
```

-And these are the flaws , I would appreciate all the help possible.
Thank you so much.

> ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
>
> ERROR: You must define the following mandatory properties for 'sistema_integracion': sonar.sources
>
> ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>
> WARN: Unable to locate 'report-task.txt' in the workspace. Did the SonarScanner succeeded?
>
> ERROR: SonarQube scanner exited with non-zero code: 1
>
> Finished: FAILURE

Comment: Por favor haga una pregunta en inglés o [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56365462/edit). Gracias por entender

Comment: Now it is in english no problem,Can you help me with my problem? Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Here is your problem:

```
ERROR: You must define the following mandatory properties for 'sistema_integracion': sonar.sources
```

You defined an absolute path:

```
sonar.source=C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\proyecto_integracion\spring_boot\src\main\java\hello
```

The path must be relative. If this is your file structure:

```
sonar-project.properties
src
  \-main
       \-java
```

Then you should set:

```
sonar.sources=src/main/java
```

Comment: If it solves your problem, then please accept the answer.